# What is a jaffer?

Tags: meaning, terminology

I have been reading the cricket commentary today and came across an unfamiliar word: *jaffer*.

> Anderson continues, surely figuring that someone is going to get
>   Morkel out soon and it bloody well better be him. Bumper, then a
>   jaffer. Morne still there though.

I looked up *jaffer* and found a definition in the Urban Dictionary:-

> A professional gaffe or lapse in judgement by a well-known public
>   figure ( especially a politician). A mistake of epic proportions.

But that doesn't seem to be what the commentator meant. So, does anyone know what a *jaffer* is, in the cricketing sense?

Comment: Is jaffer=gaffe a UKism? I've never heard the word. (I've never heard the cricket term either, but that's not surprising as I don't follow cricket. I do follow politics.)

Comment: @Jay, I've never heard of it.

Comment: Uhm.I don't exactly know the meaning, but Jaffer is a muslim name for a boy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's spelled *Jaffa*, as in Jaffa Oranges. A practically-unplayable delivery.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms#J
http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/cricket/skills/6100344.stm

It's *probably* reverse humour, like calling a tall person "Shorty" — a delivery  like a *Jaffa* is nothing like bowling an orange.

Comment: I found it spelled _jaffer_ [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/cricket/international/theashes/8211361/The-Ashes-2010-Australia-v-England-third-Test-day-three-as-it-happened.html), but what can I say? Tho I failed to comprehend it, it was a delightful read nonetheless: _No ball from Siddle, but it was a jaffer, coming in on the angle then moving away off the pitch._ There was this, too: _He gets one off the last ball of the over, a lifter that he turns to midwicket. Is that 7-4 still available at Squilliam Shill? Let's all have a lump-on._ Don't know what _lump-on_ is but it could be fun.

Answer (score 5):

In cricket terminology a [Jaffa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms#Jaffa) is

> an exceptionally well bowled, practically unplayable delivery, usually but not always from a fast bowler. Taken from the idea that a 'Jaffa' is the best type of Orange.

(That's from Wikipedia)